# Where is the list of modules under linux

Tags: linux, autotools

I am using ubuntu and building project under autotools.
I am learning to use the macro `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`, the second parameter is `list-of-modules` from [here](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/pkg_check_modules.html).

I would like to ask how to find the `list-of-modules` and pick the correct module name. I have tried `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall` and get a long list, but am not sure how to pick the module names.

Comment: Find out about `pkg-config`

Comment: Please do not use your question to provide a solution, that's the use of answers. There is no need to edit or post another answer if you don't have anything to add to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the modules is the name of the `.pc` files that are installed by various dev packages; most of those would be found in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` or `/usr/share/pkgconfig`.

(Full disclosure, I'm the author of the documentation you linked to, I guess I'll have to clarify that, thanks!)

Comment: Thank you very much. Btw, do you know how to build a Qt project with .ui files with autotools?

Comment: Sorry, I have installed opencv, I do `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(OPENCV, opencv)` it can automatically link those needed libraries for me, but I cannot find any `.*opencv.*.pc` from `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` or `/usr/share/pkgconfig`. Where can I find it. Btw, I compile and install opencv from source.

Comment: In that case the file is likely in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig. The pkg-config man page has a bit deeper explanation of the default paths that pkg-config will look into. — I'm afraid the last time I had to do Qt was in 3.x days so I'm a bit out of the loop with that :(

Comment: Thx, I found the opencv.pc file in `/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/lib/pkgconfig` finally.